# POST data to database with Retrofit

Tags: java, php, retrofit

I am stuck into a problem with posting data to a server with Retrofit.
Here is what I try to do (and what doesn't work):

This is the class that instances are converted and sent to the webservice:

```
  public class Txt {
    private String text;

    public Txt (String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText () {
        return text;
    }
  }
```

This is my Interface:

```
public interface textapi {

  @POST("/php/set_string.php")
  public void setText (Txt text, Callback<String> cb);
}
```

My Webservice:

```
<?php
$user = "user";
$database = "db";
$password = "pw";

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $databse);

$statement = mysqli_prepare ($con, "INSERT INTO votes (vote_text) VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($statment, "s", $data['text']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_close($statment);
mysqli_close($con);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data['text']);
?>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I researched and tried a lot, but I can't get it to work :/

EDIT: Okay I got an error message on Android:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true)
```

EDIT: I solved the problem by adding @Body in the interfeace:

```
 public interface textapi {

  @POST("/php/set_string.php")
  public void setText (@Body Txt text, Callback<String> cb);
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The problem is that I don't get any errors, it's just not working :/

Comment: Have you tried showing all PHP errors? Place this at the top of your page: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Did that (partially) solve it? I'll post it as an answer then if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
@POST("/php/set_string.php")
public void setText (Txt text, Callback<String> cb);
```

Should be

```
@POST("/php/set_string.php")
public void setText (@Body Txt text, Callback<String> cb);
```

since PHP is expecting raw data, by specifying the annotation @Body in front of the object text, you are telling Java to attach the object as a raw body